# Is there a MongoDB GUI desktop application for Linux?

Tags: linux, mongodb, user-interface, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

From my searches online, I've found dozens of web-based MongoDB GUIs, as well as a native desktop application for MacOS, and one for Windows. But I'm having trouble finding any desktop GUIs for Linux. I'm looking for something akin to mysql-query-browser, but for MongoDB. Anybody know of anything?

(If it matters, I'm using Kubuntu 11.04)

Comment: Would like to add https://mongobooster.com/ and mongochef https://studio3t.com/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about [UMongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/) (formerly JMongoBrowser)? I found it on [Admin UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) page.

Personally I am using web based (PHP) [Rock Mongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) - acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know about the Admin UIs page. Anyway, JMongoBrowser runs, but it's very buggy. Keeps bringing up null pointer exceptions. Also, its inferface is many ways even more cumbersome than the command-line. So I won't be using this one. Maybe I'll just use a web-based GUI. Anyway, I'm leaving this question open for now in case someone else knows of something, but if there's nothing else, I'll mark this answer accepted.

Comment: there may have been a few early bugs with jmongobrowser but there is no outstanding bug I know of. The logs are not null pointers, just warning from the swing library. If you find any bug or have ideas to improve the interface, feel free to open tickets on github, thx in advance!

Comment: Seems to work pretty well for me!

Comment: @ajg, Hmm, maybe it was just a quirk of the setup of my system that JMongoBrowser wasn't working. I've got a recent fresh install of Kubuntu now, so I'll give it another shot. In the meantime, I've been using `phpmoadmin` (http://www.phpmoadmin.com/) which is an ugly-looking interface but actually works pretty well.

Comment: Unfortunately this link no longer works.

Comment: @Andrew: fixed, the program changed the name from JMongoBrowser to UMongo and old link was broken.

Comment: `UMongo ` link does not open  // should be https://github.com/agirbal/umongo

Answer (score 12):

[Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/), Shell-centric cross-platform MongoDB management tool. Work on most linux systems, have deb and rpm packages.

Comment: It's what I use in Windows.  Unfortunately for Linux I had to compile it myself, and it was a PITA given all of the dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using (or willing to use) Eclipse, the [MonjaDB plugin](http://www.jumperz.net/index.php?i=2&a=0&b=9) seems pretty nice. I prefer it over Rockmongo or UMongo on Linux.

Comment: Actually, Eclipse happens to be my day-to-day editor! Just installed MonjaDB and it rocks! Way better than anything else I've found for Linux. I'm leaving the check mark on the other answer, since it covers the general Linux non-Eclipse case, which is what the question asked for, but I will be using MonjaDB from now on!

Answer (score 1):

[qMongoFront](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qmongofront/) is a QT based MongoDB GUI client on linux.It is totally free and opensouce.

Answer (score 0):

Get the full list of app over at:

http://mongodb-tools.com/

And so far my favorite is:

http://www.litixsoft.de/english/mms/